How can I create a new table using linear interpolation on multiple data subsets using Power Query M?
I’ve been able to use the linked answer below to construct a new column interpolating data from a single set of data (e.g., one interest rate curve).
I can’t figure out how to leverage this for a table that includes multiple interest rate curves, where separate interpolation calculations would occur for each curve's initial data set. Please see example table below of three curves, but I need the logic to care for any possible number of curves.
I need to build the new table where unique interpolation occurs for each separate interest rate curve’s initial set of [BusinessDays, InterestRate].
The expected output is a new table calculating the interpolated InterestRate values for every day from the first BusinessDay to last BusinessDay for each CurveName. In this example, a total of 820 rows which equals all days, inclusive, from start date to end date for the three curves. For example, 376 rows for SOFR (# days inclusive from start day 39 to end day 414).

Original solution for linear interpolation on one data set
I have tried updating the Power Query M code to build a nested table for each separate CurveName’s [BusinessDays, InterestRate] data set, but haven’t been able to get the code to work.
Thank you in advance

What is the expected output ?

It would be a calculated column calculating the interpolated InterestRate values for every day from the first BusinessDay to last BusinessDay for each CurveName. I will update the question to include the expected output.

still not clear about your question. pls paste the expected output here. why 376 rows for SOFR?

I updated the post so hopefully it’s more clear on the expected output. Interpolated set of interest rates for each curve across every day within each curve’s start-end period.

I have posted this as an answer because, when tested using the Power BI diagnostic tools, it seems to execute much more quickly than the answer provided by @vmhung.
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"CurveName", type text}, {"BusinessDays", Int64.Type}, {"InterestRate", Percentage.Type}}),
    
    Interpolated = List.Accumulate(
        List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[CurveName]),
        #table({},{}),
        (s,c)=>
            Table.Combine({s,
            let 
                #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([CurveName] = c)),
                #"All Days" = 
                    Table.FromColumns(
                        {{List.Min(#"Filtered Rows"[BusinessDays])..List.Max(#"Filtered Rows"[BusinessDays])}}, 
                        type table[Days=Int64.Type]),
                #"Join Days" = Table.Join(#"Filtered Rows","BusinessDays",#"All Days","Days", JoinKind.FullOuter),
                #"Interpolated Rates" = Table.AddColumn(#"Join Days","Rates", (r)=>
                    if r[InterestRate]<>null 
                        then r[InterestRate]
                    else let 
                        t1=Table.Last(Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [BusinessDays]<r[Days])),
                        x1 = t1[BusinessDays],
                        y1 = t1[InterestRate],
                        t2= Table.First(Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [BusinessDays]>= r[Days])),
                        x2 = t2[BusinessDays],
                        y2 = t2[InterestRate],
                        m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1),
                        v = ((r[Days]-x1) * m) + y1               
                    in v, Percentage.Type/* [x1=x1, y1=y1, x2=x2,y2=y2, m=m, v=v]*/),
                #"Remove Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Interpolated Rates",{"BusinessDays","InterestRate"}),
                #"Rename Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Remove Columns",{{"Days","BusinessDays"},{"Rates","InterestRate"}}),
                #"Fill Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Rename Columns",{"CurveName"})
                    
        in #"Fill Down"}))
in
    Interpolated


Thanks, I actually need the calculated table of interpolated values for each curve. I'm using these values in subsequent calculations that could reference any grid point day's interest rate, rather than the sparse initial set of days.

@CH So you have neglected to show an example of what you really want from the data you present. For example, what kind of interpolation? In your title you write Linear Interpolation which will produce a straight line from the data. If that's the case, in Power BI you can use the DAX LINEST or LINESTX functions and construct a new table.

It is linearly interpolating between values, which is what my expected graph of the output shows. I tried to paste in the actual table output but it was too large. DAX LINEST/LINESTX would be useful but only for a best fit line, not interpolation between all starting values.
Thanks for the advice on this. I've gotten vmhung's code working to produce the interpolated data for these curves.
